# Disable scroll in console in eclipse when I'm not at the bottom

Tags: eclipse

I'm using the eclipse console for long, fast-running logs.

I can't find a way to get this console to behave like all other consoles, i.e. if it is scrolled down to the end, then it should scroll automatically, and if not, it should stop scrolling.

Is there a way (configuration, plugin) to achieve this?

Answer (score 14):

As of [Eclipse Mars (4.5)](https://projects.eclipse.org/releases/mars), and with the fix for [this bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=149393), what you're after is now the default behaviour.

That is, you no longer have to manually toggle the `Scroll Lock` button - scrolling up (e.g. with the mouse wheel, but also by clicking the scrollbar or even moving the cursor up inside the console) automatically turns scroll locking on, while scrolling down to (near) the bottom turns it back off.

Great for some scenarios, but I sometimes find myself wishing for the old behaviour back. It doesn't seem as though there's an option, though.

Answer (score 10):

No, there is no such thing before Eclipse Mars (4.5). You have to toggle the `Scroll Lock` toolbar button manually.

Comment: Ok, thx. I'm just wondering a little bit that nobody is interested in such a more intuitive behavior.

Comment: @user1310372 agreed, I would like a smarter scroll lock feature as well. You should submit it as a feature request.

Comment: Good news!  It looks like this will have been fixed when Eclipse Mars (4.5) comes out, about a month from now.  https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=149393

Comment: @JoshuaGoldberg: Confirmed, and added as an answer for anyone looking up this old question as I did. :-)

Comment: what does scroll lock mean? the scroll doesn't move when the scroll is locked?

Answer (score 2):

**Windows > Preferences > Console > (un/check)**

Enable auto scroll lock.
(I use Eclipse for Ent. Java Devs - version 2019-09 R (4.13.0))

[image]